# How to remove a payment option

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, backend, credit-card

We need to remove completely the **payment option** cc saved, please can someone explain how?

Answer (score 0):

To remove completely the **payment step** in checkout/onepage, you need to change different files.

1) you need to override the **block** : `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage`.

2) you need to override the **controller** : `OnepageController.php`

3) you need to update these phtml files :

- `checkout/onepage.phtml`
- `checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`
- `checkout/onepage/progress.phtml`
- `checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml`

4) also the Email templates :

- `template\email\sales\order_new.html`
- `template\email\sales\order_new_guest.html`

You have here in [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/) the complete process to customize all these files.

Good luck.

Comment: I want to remove it from the site complete so that it can be enabled at all